# Why blender doesn't render my trees

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, modular-tree-addon

I created this particle plane with trees, but when I render cycles or eevee it doesn't render trees.
What I could do?
[image]
[image]
https://we.tl/t-wyAYR30YpS blender file
[image]

Comment: you can improve your question by giving us needed informations like settings, outliner screenshots etc. or....provide your blend file.

Comment: I don't touch settings, there is a setting for this?

Comment: Provide your blend file before moderators close your question because you didn’t provide enough information

Comment: I share the blend file @Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did something, which Blender does not support this way.

You cannot put a particle system as rendered object for another particle system.

If you change the rendered object to e.g. path here:

[image]

then Blender renders something - of course NOT what you want. But this answers your question.
Then you get this render output:
[image]

By the way: Why did you use hair as particle system? For trees the "normal" particles are good to go...